# Vue-cli 3 component library to support SSR

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

I am creating a custom component library that i want to share across multiple domains.

**Domains**:

- Each domain has its own instance of nuxt
- Each domain has `my-component-lib` registered in `package.json`
- Each domain registers the lib as a plugin

  ```
  //my-component-lib.js
  import components from 'my-component-lib'
  import Vue from 'vue'

  export default ({ store }) => {
   Vue.use(components, { store: store })
  }

  //nuxt.config.js
  plugins: [
    /*Desired option 1*/ '@/plugins/my-component-lib',
    /*Currently using*/ { src: '@/plugins/my-component-lib', ssr: false }
  ]
  ```

**my-component-lib:**

- Setup using vue-cli 3
- The library is composed of basic html tags and CSS ex `<input ></input>`. The styling is important and i would like to keep it together with the component `(extract:false)` so i can pull individual components out and not worry about importing a css file.

  ```
  //vue.config.js
  module.exports = {
   outputDir: 'dist',
   lintOnSave: false,
   css: {
    extract: false
   }
  }
  ```

setup for production using `"production": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name sc components/index.js"`

**Problems:**

1. Using the desired option, when i run nuxt `npm run dev` i get a `document is not defined` in function `addStyle (obj /* StyleObjectPart */) {..}` within `sc.common.js`
2. Using the current option, i get a hydration error`(The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content.)` which is fixed if i wrap the components within `<no-ssr>` tags which i do not want to do.

I want to compile my component library to work with SSR and not have to import a large css file

Comment: How do you fixed the second problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Changing the CSS prop fixed the issues for me

Comment: FYI If you are nesting html tags inside <p> tag throws that error

Comment: Also make sure ur not using document or Windows until the component is mounted

Comment: I switched the css prop to true but i a still having the same issue. Are you using scss or sass in your project?

Comment: If i remove all spaces and I remove all HTML code formatting then the component works but this can not be the long term solution

Comment: What that sounds like is the code is an issue

Comment: What I would do is comment out most of it and then test piece by piece alternatively lookup an html validator online and copy in the html

Comment: Start a question and I'll look at it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209739/discussion-between-patrick-and-jujubes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 ...
 css: {
  extract: false
 }
 ...
```

to `true`

Comment: But doesn't that export the CSS and you're again left with a CSS file you need to import?

Comment: @HerrSiering - It did - what i ended up doing was using `rollup` which handles it all - i am using `vue` and rollup makes it easy. The only thing is that `rollup` doesnt handle lazy loading `components (ex:{ lazyLoadedComp:()=>import('file location') }` ) but that worked out ok in my case